# Request for server program using a threadpool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I am looking for code for a server program that accepts several client connections using the **threadpool** concept, such that each client can send a file to the server, and the server should respond by sending the corresponding response file.

I am asking this because at this point I am able to get several client requests, but I am not able to generate responses that include the corresponding response files.

Comment: No, we're not writing it for you. Show us what you've tried, and we'll comment.

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement a bit ? Show it with a scenario. Do you want a behavior similar to a servet and server container ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of modern J2EE application servers support that concept. Transform your application into a WAR and play with server thread pool/request time out settings.

**UPDATE**: If you don't like application servers, then use [Executors](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) utility class from JDK, create a new ExceutorService through that by wrapping your long running action into Runnable interface and creating a ThreadFactory for that, and then use [awaitTermination](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method. If it returns false, then your thread encountered a time out and you can send some nice error message to your client.

Comment: hiee guys actually even i tried to paste my code here but its is not allowing me to paste that much code....so i asked u for a server pgm which uses thread...mainly server should accept sum file like xml or text from several clients and that file should be processed and respective response files shuld b sent back to respective clients

Comment: Sounds like a web server accepting HTTP GET/POST/PUT requests ;) Try tomcat, jetty, jboss, glassfish. It's very hard to give any advice here as you are not very descriptive about the actual problem you have.